# Ayuda con la indentacion en Eclipse

Tags: eclipse

Como ocultar esos caracteres especiales que se muestran al final de cada línea, debido a la indentacion >> ¤¶ ?

Después de buscar la opción en preferencias y no encontrarla, me veo obligado a pedir ayuda.

[image: Recorte Eclipse Screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

Ve a Preferencias > General > Editores > Editores de texto. Hay una opción con el texto "Mostrar caracteres en blanco". Asegúrate de que la opción no esté marcada.